# Initialize XAML page once when application is running UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to init XAML and its code behind page once when that page is open. I try to register it with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` but it still initializes every time I navigate to it. So do we have any way to keep it alive during the application lifetime?

**UPDATE**

I registered my XAML file and code behind with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<MyPage>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

But it still run the constructor every time we navigate to that page.
In ContainerControlledLifetimeManager comment say:

> A Microsoft.Practices.Unity.LifetimeManager that holds onto the
>   instance given to it. When the
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager is
>   disposed, the instance is disposed with it.

Comment: Try singleton lifetime? Not very clear without any code mind.

Comment: I updated my question. Could you let me know more information about singleton lifetime?

Comment: It would only create one for the lifetime of the container/lifetime of the application. Its not quite what you want, but you are currently creating one each time you need the page and dont want that, so try singleton

Comment: Could you give me the exact name of singleton lifetime? Do we register it like my lifetime above or just make it like singleton pattern?

Comment: I apologise, looks like you are already using the singleton lifetime according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835728/unity-singleton-code seems like you have another problem at hand. Why do you think its being recreated multiple times?

Comment: Just debug and I saw it jumps into constructor method multiple times :D I think we can do this with XAML page. it needs to recreate every time we display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting `NavigationCacheMode` of your page to either `Required` or `Enabled` instead?

Comment: Set NavigationCacheMode  = Required is OK for me. Thanks!